# how can i cast server error message to AFError

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, swift5, jsondecoder

i am unable to find some way to cast custom message to AFError

```
    class APIClient {
@discardableResult
    static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (Result<T, AFError>)->Void) -> DataRequest {
        return AF.request(route).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                completion(.success(value))
            case .failure(let error):
                let err = MYError(description: "here goes some custom error message")
                let customErr = err .asAFError
                completion(.failure(customErr!))
                
            }
    }
}
```

and my custom error message struct

```
    struct MYError : Error{
let description : String
var localizedDescription: String {
    return NSLocalizedString(description, comment: "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what AFError you want to cast your error to? That's the first step to your answer because the AFError is a type of error class not one specific error. Here's my approach.

First I would change the error to an enum Errors defined as an Error just like the Struct you had. Then add your custom error as a case. Define your description and specify there what you would like the error message to be for each case (specific error).

Second, define what your Error should correspond to in an AFError for each case. This way you can specify and pass the data that will be required for some of the AFErrors like the example of SomeOtherError.

```swift
enum Errors: Error {    
    var localizedDescription: String {
        var str: String = ""
        switch self {
        case .MyError: str = "Some custom error message"
        case .SomeOtherError: str = "This would be another error and message"
        }
        
        return NSLocalizedString(str, comment: "")
    }
    
    var asAFError: AFError? {
        switch self {
        case .MyError: return .explicitlyCancelled
        case .SomeOtherError(let data): return .sessionDeinitialized(data)
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    
    case MyError
    case SomeOtherError(Data)
}
```

Lastly use a guard statement incase you throw and error that cannot be defined as an AFError, then pass that error to your completion like normal.

```swift
class APIClient {
    @discardableResult
    static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route: APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (Result<T, AFError>)->Void) -> DataRequest {
        return AF.request(route).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                completion(.success(value))
            case .failure(let error):
                guard let err = Errors.MyError.asAFError
                else { return error }
                completion(.failure(err))
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer this..actually i just to want to display error message which is returned from server in any case